# Need help figuring out best algorithm for automating a DB loading process below

Tags: android, database, user-interface, content-management-system, integration

(A) I have 10 different Suppliers; I sell Hats on their Behalf.

1)  5 of my Suppliers produce hats themselves and sell through other online shops. They rely on traditional methods to manage, so no systems available.

Information has to be manually keyed in through a secure page, which connects to my DB.

2)  With my other 5 Suppliers, we have setup an automated feed, so I can directly access their DB/CRM, which is connected directly to my DB.

As a result, I am able to track down any real time data and product availability.

(B) Database, with stored product data.

(C) Output: UI page to display Available hats and product information to Buying Customers.

Issue to figure out…

To help improve customer service and ensure Buying Customers are viewing correct merchandize information:

I need help on figuring out on…

a)  How will I be able to ensure information currently held within my DB is kept up-to-date on a frequent basis from 5 of my Suppliers from point A1)…?

As they cannot afford to purchase systems, they are currently manually keying in their information and selling through other online shops. Therefore, making things much more difficult to keep track of.

Please Note:

Need to avoid sending constant emails & Alerts as reminders to update on stock.

Only time they will receive constant emails or alerts, is when a customer has made a purchase or request!

Overall aim is to make sure that a Buying Customer is purchasing stock that is only Available to buy from Suppliers.

What is the best process or solution?